# How to approach modular arithmetic problem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let p, q and A be three positive integers. I have the following equation:

$$(A mod p) mod q = (A mod q)mod p$$

Find all the ordered pairs $(p, q)$ which satisfy the above equation such that $$1 <=p < q <= N$$
and $N$ <= $10^7$, $A<=10^7$.

**My approach:**

As p is less than $q$ in LHS, $$(A modp) modq = Amodp$$

Now $$Amodp = (A mod q)mod p$$
If we consider $Amodq = X$ (some constant), then $$A = Amodq$$
Which  is only possible when $A< q$.
**I'm not able to proceed ahead. Kindly help.**

Comment: Do not answer this question.  This is from an ongoing [Codechef](https://www.codechef.com/MAY21C/problems/MODEQ) competition.

Comment: @lulu the contest is over now. remove your comment.

Comment: Can someone confirm the contest is over?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff it can be verified from the link provided by lulu

Comment: @lulu please remove your comment. So that i can get suitable community insights for this problem.